# Validate before Stripe Checkout modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, stripe-payments

I have a simple form that has a select box to select the product, radio group to select the quantity and then a checkbox that if checked, shows a select box and an input field that becomes required if check box is selected.

```
<form action="stripeprocess.php">
<!-- fields and structure here, product, quantity, join mailing list checkbox and other mailing list questions that appear when checkbox is ticked -->
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button id="stripe-button" class="bin">Enter Pay Details with Stripe</button>
<script>
$('#stripe-button').click(function(){
  var token = function(res){
  var $id = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
  var $email = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeEmail />').val(res.email);
  $('#order-form').append($id).append($email).submit();
};                        

StripeCheckout.open({
  key:          'hidden',
  name:         'hidden',
  image:        'logo.png',
  description:  'Complete your Order',
  panelLabel:   'Complete Order',
  billingAddress: true,
  zipCode:      true,
  token:            token
});

return false;
});
</script>
</form>
```

Everything works and order is processing, I just need to add validation. I know how to write the rules in jQuery validate, but I am not sure how to do that and implement it to run the validate and then the stripe checkout after success validate.

So in the simplest way of code, I would like to accomplish this:

```
if(submit button is pressed) {
  run jQuery validate on forms

  if(jQuery validate successful) {
     run stripe and launch modal
  } 
}
```

Can someone assist me with this or point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: What plugin do you use for form validation?

Comment: I do not have a preference if you have one that would work for this, I have worked with https://jqueryvalidation.org in the past.

Comment: So if you can use this plugin you only need to write this: `$('#your-form').validate( // your rules)`

Comment: I understand how to validate a form but I don't understand how to load the stripe modal checkout process after jQuery validate does it's run through my rules and is success.

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to accomplish this:

```
if (submit button is pressed) {
    // run jQuery validate on forms // part 1

    if(jQuery validate successful) {
        // run stripe and launch modal // part 2
    } 
}
```

For "part 1", you are not supposed to have to worry about capturing the submit or click event.  The plugin will capture these automatically *after* it's properly initialized.

So for "part 1" simply initialize the jQuery Validate plugin within the DOM Ready event handler by attaching the `.validate()` method to the `form` element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initialize plugin
    $('form[action="stripeprocess.php"]').validate({
        rules: { ....
```

For "part 2", you can *"do something"* upon successful validation by putting it within the `submitHandler` function...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initialize plugin
    $('form[action="stripeprocess.php"]').validate({
        rules: { 
            ....
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            // fires on valid form

            // run stripe and launch modal

            // form.submit();  // regular submit
        }
        ....
```

**Although, if `action="stripeprocess.php"` represents launching Stripe, then you wouldn't need the `submitHandler` at all, since that's already the plugin's built-in functionality.**